# I can't validate my email on html template

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I created a HTML Registration form with some fields.And also I set validation on each field..But my email validation is not working properly.The given below is my HTML page.

home.html

```
<html >
<head>

       <!--external javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateForm()
{

 var x=document.forms["form1"]["firstname"];
 if (x.value=="")
   {
  alert("Please enter the First name.");
  x.focus();
  return false;
   }



 x=document.forms["form1"]["lastname"];
 if(x.value=="")
   {
  alert("Please enter the Last name.");
  x.focus();
  return false;
 } 


 if((document.form1.gender[0].checked==false)&&(document.form1.gender[1].checked==false))
 {
  document.form1.gender[0].focus();
  alert("Please select a gender.");
  return false;
 }
 var dd=document.form1.dd.value;
 var mmm=document.form1.mmm.value;
 var yyyy=document.form1.yyyy.value;
 if(!validdate(dd,mmm,yyyy))
 {
  return false;
 }

 x= document.getElementById("email");
 if(x.value==null || x.value=="" )
 {
  alert("Please enter the Email.");
  x.value="";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }



 if(confirm("Do you want to submit the form?"))
{
alert("Registration Form Submitted Successfully.");
}
else
return false;

}
function validdate(dd,mm,yyyy)
 {
  var dateobj = new Date(yyyy, mm, dd);
  var datecurrent= new Date();
  if((dateobj.getMonth()!=mm)||(dateobj.getDate()!=dd)||(dateobj.getFullYear()!=yyyy)||(dateobj>datecurrent))
  {
   alert("Please select a valid date.");
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }



 function confirmreset()
 {
  return confirm("Do you want to reset the form?");
 }




</script>

</head>
<body>

<center>
<h1>Demo Registration Form</h1>
<form name="form1"  method="post" action="success.html">

<table border='0'>
 <tr>
  <td><LABEL for="firstname">First Name:<sup style="color:#F00">*</sup> </LABEL></td>
         <td><INPUT type="text" id="firstname"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><LABEL for="lastname">Last Name:<sup style="color:#F00">*</sup> </LABEL></td>
  <td><INPUT type="text" id="lastname"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td><LABEL for="gender">Gender:<sup style="color:#F00">*</sup> </LABEL></td> <td><INPUT type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male
   <INPUT type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><LABEL for="dob">Date of Birth:<sup style="color:#F00">*</sup> </LABEL></td>
  <td> 
  <select id="dd">
        <option value="dd">DD</option>
        <script type="text/javascript">
   for(var i=1;i<32;i++)
    document.write("<option value='"+i+"'>" + i+"</option> ");
   </script>
        </select>
                </select>
                 <select id="mmm">
         <option value="mmm">MMM</option>
         <option value="0">JAN</option>
         <option value="1">FEB</option>
         <option value="2">MAR </option>
         <option value="3">APR</option>
         <option value="4">MAY</option>
         <option value="5">JUN</option>
         <option value="6">JUL</option>
         <option value="7">AUG</option>
         <option value="8">SEP</option>
         <option value="9">OCT</option>
         <option value="10">NOV</option>
         <option value="11">DEC</option>
        </select>
        <select id="yyyy">
           <option value="yyyy"selected>YYYY</option>
        <script type="text/javascript">
   var dt= new Date();
   for(var i=1979;i<=dt.getFullYear();i++)
    document.write("<option value='"+i+"'>" + i+"</option> ");
  </script>
  </select>

  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><LABEL for="email" style="text-align:left;">Email:<sup style="color:#F00">*</sup> </LABEL></td>
  <td><INPUT type="text" id="email"></INPUT>  
  </td>


 </tr>


 <tr>
  <td></td><td><br/><INPUT type="submit" onClick="return validateForm()" value="Submit">
  <INPUT type="reset" onClick="return confirmreset()"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td></td><td style="font-size:12px;text-align:right;"><br/><i style="color:red;font-size:12px;align:right;" >* - Mandatory</i></td>
 </tr>
    </table>
 </FORM></center>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I set email validation. And also I would like to set `password and confirm password fields` with the given code?Is it possible for me?Please help

Comment: use <INPUT type="email" id="email"> instead of type="text"

Answer (score -1):

You can use input methods for this.

For the password method:

> You can create a password and a password confirm like this.
>   `<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>` and for the confirm password you can use the same, like this for example `<input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>`

To check if the password matches the confirm password you can use this php code:

> `if($password != $cpassword) {
>       $error = true;
>       $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
>   }`

And what do you mean with 'Email validation'? If it means the same like a password confirmation field but instead with an email you can use this:

> `<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>`
>   and for the confirmation email: `<input type="text" name="cemail" placeholder="Email"/>`

Now you can check the email on the same way as the password.

If it means to check your email if it is a correct email with an '@' and valid structure,... You can use this php code:

> `if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
>       $error = true;
>       $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
>   }`
>
> Here is '$email' the name from the input.

You can echo the error by typing `echo $email_error`
I hoped this helped. Any more help let me know!